# GridColumn Group in java

Tags: java, swt

Is it possible to keep one gridColumnGroup under another gridColumnGroup? I have been able to keep a gridColumn under a GridColumnGroup using the code below

> GridColumnGroup grdInvestment = new GridColumnGroup(grid,
>   SWT.CENTER);       grdInvestment.setText("Investment");        GridColumn
>   gridColumn_2 = new GridColumn(grdInvestment, SWT.NONE);
>   gridColumn_2.setText("Short");         gridColumn_2.setWidth(40);
>   GridColumn gridColumn_3 = new GridColumn(grdInvestment, SWT.NONE);
>   gridColumn_3.setText("Medium");        gridColumn_3.setWidth(58);

but now i want to keep a gridColumnGroup under another gridColumnGroup. I have attached an Image and i want to use the concept of GridColumn Group to make columns just like the one in the image. In the image A,B and E are columnGroups and C,D,F and G are columns of a grid. [image: oolumns]

Comment: Aren't A, B and E column groups rather than columns? (In fact, these all are cells, not columns in a strict sense :) )

Comment: Yes A, B and E are column groups , i'm sorry that i wrote A,B and E are columns . Only C,D, F and G are columns.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's reported as a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=240213 .